# How to get the name of the DynamicImport in nextJs / React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-import

I have this code inside a React Component which imports dynamicaly different components and store them into the variable DynamicCoomponent, and I really nead to get somehow the name of the component which was imported succesfully.

Alternatively I would like to store the path of the inserted component into a state, but I cannot find the correct syndax for a .then function

I am using NextJs in a React Project

```
   const DynamicComponent = dynamic(
        () =>
            import(`./${type}/${templateFolder}/${publication}_${templateName}+${channel}`)
                .catch((e) => {
                    errors.push(e.message);
                    return import(`./${type}/${templateFolder}/${templateName}+${channel}`);
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    errors.push(e.message);
                    return import(`./${type}/${templateFolder}/${publication}_${templateName}`);
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    errors.push(e.message);
                    return import(`./${type}/${templateFolder}/${templateName}`);
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    errors.push(e.message);
                    console.error(errors);
                    return import("./EmptyComponent");
                }),
        { ssr: false }
    )
```

And Later I am using this as

```
return (
        <>
            <DynamicComponent />
        </>
    );
```

This works perfectly but i need something more here that i cannot do.
I want to get the name of the DynamicComponent which was imported and i cannot do it.
If i console.log(DynamicComponent) i get the whole component and not the name itself.
Can somebody help me ?

Comment: maybe `DynamicComponent.displayName` or `DynamicComponent.name`? Your component should not be an anonymous fn in that case. Either `class MyComponent ...` or `function MyComponent() {}`.

Comment: Your dynamic import has all dynamic parts: https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import

Comment: DynamicComponent.displayName & DynamicComponent.name gives me back "LoadableComponent" and not the actual name of the imported component.
i need to get as a string the name of the imported component